# CouchDB - "Plucking" nearest neighbour documents from a view.

Tags: database, oop, mapreduce, couchdb

Not sure how this question will sound, but figured I'd throw out the Bat signal anyway...
I have a dataset similar to the following:

```
[
    { name: "Peter", score: 1000 },
    { name: "James", score: 800 },
    { name: "John", score: 600 },
    { name: "Saul", score: 400 },
    { name: "David", score: 200 }
]
```

Now there are a few things I'd like to do with this collection, but the main function I'm keen on is one to take a given record and find the documents that sit directly above and below that item in the score table, like;

```
[
    { name: "James", score: 800 },
    -> { name: "John", score: 600 },
    { name: "Saul", score: 400 }
]
```

I'd also like to create a view that looks like this:

```
[
    { key: 1, value: { name: "Peter", score: 1000 } },
    { key: 2, value: { name: "James", score: 800 } },
    { key: 3, value: { name: "John", score: 600 } },
    { key: 4, value: { name: "Saul", score: 400 } },
    { key: 5, value: { name: "David", score: 200 } }
]
```

I can't help but feel that the two problems are related.
I'm also keen to perform the "pluck" in as small a number of REST requests as possible...

I'd also happily accept a solution that relies on the application layer, but again, I'd like to avoid multiple trips to the DB, and would also like to avoid pulling out more data than necessary.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a view that has the score as a key. The map function just needs to do `emit(doc.score, null)`, where doc is the document passed to the function. If you query this view with `startkey=600`, `limit=2`, and `descending=false`, you will get the documents with scores of 600 and 800. If you query with `startkey=600`, `limit=2` and `descending=true`, you will get the documents with scores of 600 and 400.

To get all documents in descending score order, you'd just query with descending=true and no other parameters. You won't get a `key: n` field of course, but you can easily add that in your application layer.

Comment: This is the solution I currently have in mind. 

I'm keen on 'key: n', because I want to avoid having to pull out a result set of 1000 rows (or whatever) to find out just where "Peter" sits in the table. One other thing I'd like to do, is pull out a document by ID, and determine it's rank (and possibly, pluck the neighbours) without having to go back to the DB, and query the score property. So I'm trying to sum up just how complicated that all might be... Is that reasonable?

Comment: In general case, you have to calculate your `key` at application layer, especially if you trying to build live rating list. Reason is simple: views are updates incrementally for only changed documents. If you add Mike with score 1200, your view will be updated only for this doc, but others remains untouched. This may produce awkward results.

Comment: @Charlie: You could get key:n by using a list function on top of the view.

Comment: If I choose to select a document by name, then I how would I retrieve the rank / key:n? Would I have to call the list function each time? I would like to keep the entire model in CouchDB, definitely, but I am struggling with this one. Hence the question.

Comment: Had another look at the problem, and found a solution that relies on CouchDB's total_rows, and offset values. Both properties can be found in every successful view request response object. Using them avoids the need to create a 'key=n'.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use score as key? In this case you may build rating charts and query for persons that have score in some range. Your map function:

```
function(doc){
    emit(doc.score, {'name': doc.name, 'score': doc.score})
}
```

// not sure that you still needed in such value

Now, if you call your view you'll receive:

```
{
  "total_rows": 5, "offset": 0, "rows": [
    {"id": "1", "key": 200, "value": {"name": "David", "score": 200}},
    {"id": "2", "key": 400, "value": {"name": "Saul", "score": 400}},
    {"id": "3", "key": 600, "value": {"name": "John", "score": 600}},
    {"id": "4", "key": 800, "value": {"name": "James", "score": 800}},
    {"id": "5", "key": 1000, "value": {"name": "Peter", "score": 1000}}
  ]
}
```

Looks not like top ratings. Let's add `descending=true` query parameter:

```
{"total_rows": 5, "offset": 0, "rows": [
  {"id": "5", "key": 1000, "value": {"name": "Peter", "score": 1000}},
  {"id": "4", "key": 800, "value": {"name": "James", "score": 800}},
  {"id": "3", "key": 600, "value": {"name": "John", "score": 600}},
  {"id": "2", "key": 400, "value": {"name": "Saul", "score": 400}},
  {"id": "1", "key": 200, "value": {"name": "David", "score": 200}}
]}
```

Good! Now you may apply `startkey` / `endkey` query parameters to query things within specified range. Let's take `startkey=799&endkey=401`. Note that border values are included in response:

```
{"total_rows":5,"offset":2,"rows":[
  {"id":"3","key":600,"value":{"name":"John","score":600}}
]}
```

The result query will looks as `http://localhost:5984/db/_design/ddoc/_view/by_score?descending=true&startkey=799&endkey=401`

Answer (score -1):

I think I'll create a lightweight view of the dataset (emit("score", null), as suggested by Kxepal and Kim) pull it out, cache it, and use the changes feed to keep it fresh.

That way, I'd end up hitting the database less. That should make the "plucking" process in someway easier, as I can explicitly add a 'rank' property to the cached object properties/elements, and use that to cherry pick stuff.

*Update:*

Though the above could work as a solution (a possible use case for Redis?), using the view response total_rows and offset values make retrieving a document 'rank' trivial (based on a 'score' view, as suggested in the two answers above)...

The only problem that still remains is the "pluck" itself, which may still need two separate  API calls, but that might no be so bad...

Still open to suggestions though.

Cheers. :)